# Don't render backbone marionette collection view on change?

Tags: javascript, sockets, backbone.js, marionette

Working on an app that has real time messages with socket.io, I also need to save the messages. I choose to use mongodb and on the client side I am using backbone.

My problem is when I emit a new message all the sockets/users get the message in real time, but the socket/user that sent the message gets it twice, once from the socket and once from the collection re-rendering.

Here is what my collection view looks like.

```
module.exports = CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

    className: 'collection',
    initialize: function() {
        //this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);
    },
    itemView: MessageView

});
```

I commented out `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);`. So I am asking this question because maybe marionette by default renders the CollectionView? Maybe someone has an explanation for how I can prevent the socket/user that sends a message from being appended twice?

**Edit:** Just got an idea, instead of appending the message I could just fetch the collection when a new message is made? I tried it and it works, maybe there is a better way? I'm still thinking, and am open to new ideas!

**Edit:** This worked pretty well for me. Instead of appending the html, I just make a GET request to all the sockets connected, that way they get the fresh data.

```
createMessage: function(data) {
    window.App.data.messages.fetch({
        success: function() {
            console.log('success')
        }
    }); 
    //this.$el.find('.message-content').append('<div class="message"><b>'+data.username+':</b>'+data.message+'</div>');
    window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Chat View: Received a new message!');
}
```

Only issue with the above is the sequence is POST, then GET within milliseconds of each other, so the GET request may return data before the POST fully finishes.

So I am trying to figure out how I can set a callback so that when the POST successfully adds to the collection make the GET. I'll share the solution if I come to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing your socket.io client code, but I think your second approach is better. Socket should only send/receive data. I assume you have at least 1 event in your socket for "receiveMessage" and 1 emit for "sendMessage".

I think you could, in your client-side socket:

1. When receiving a message (or I'm notified that I have a new message), add the message to your collection using Collection.add(message). Marionette will render that message for you.
2. When sending a message, just add it to your collection, or wait for a callback from the server (see the docs) to be sure it was received correctly before adding to the collection.

Never, never, append something to the view's HTML with jQuery if you're using Marionette view! ;)

For your initial message load, use Collection.fetch() the first time (for example, as soon as your socket is connected) to get all messages that were already on the server. From that point on, add individual messages as they come instead of fetching them all (you'll be saving bandwith).

What I do in a similar application, is send from the socket a "Hello" message upon first connection, that includes the data I need. Then I just do Collection.reset(data) with what was sent from the socket, and you're good to go. Your socket will initialize your collection and will be updating it one message at a time.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey sorry for being so late, been flirting around with a lot of new things. I definitely like this approach! Trying it out now :)